# Dinamically gridview paging

Tags: asp.net, webforms, .net-4.8

When generating a GridView dynamically i assign the `PageIndexChanging` event in the code-behind. As shown in the following code:

```
gridView.AllowPaging = true;
gridView.PageSize = 10;
gridView.CssClass = "table table-stripped";
gridView.PagerStyle.HorizontalAlign = HorizontalAlign.Right;

gridView.DataSource = results;
gridView.DataBind();

gridView.PageIndexChanged += GridView_PageIndexChanged;
gridView.PageIndexChanging += GridView_PageIndexChanging;
```

and in the GridView_PageIndexChanged and GridView_PageIndexChanging events the conventional page change routine.

However, when trying to switch pages, the GridView exception *'gvVisao' triggered the PageIndexChanging event, which was not handled.* is triggered.

Comment: where you have written these codes.. on `page load`?

Comment: Yes, i've a page. On page load i call a function that generate my gridview. But i have the gridview in page.